# Develop a Cuda DLL working with different Runtime versions

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

I've a problem with a library developed in Visual C++ with Cuda.
I want to use my dll on different computers, all with NVIDIA drivers, but it depends
by CUDART32_42_9.DLL and CUBLAS32_43_9.DLL; so, depending on 32_42_9, it doesn't work with any different cuda version: neither inferiror (that is reasonable) nor superior (that is my problem). 
Have you got any suggestion about how to solve the problem? Do I have to deploy my library with  CUDART32_42_9.DLL  and  CUBLAS32_43_9.DL attached?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the responsibility of the application developer to redistribute the necessary CUDA libraries with the application. The EULA.txt document in the CUDA Toolkit doc directory has a section Attachment A that defines Redistributable Software. Redistributable software includes but is not limited to cudart* and cublas*. See EULA.txt for more details.

The end user will need to download a compliant version of the NVIDIA graphics driver for their platform.